4.2 Subsurface Scattering Random Walk (Skin) Problem
Does anyone know what is causing these edges in Blender 4.2 Cycles? Object is shaded smooth. Has something to do with the Random Walk (skin) version of SSS. Random Walk also has these edges. Christensen-Burley does not, but the SSS doesn't look as realistic as (skin). This is particularly problematic around tight angles.
I ran into this in earlier versions of Blender and was able to figure out a solution, but I can't seem to figure this out in 4.2.



